# Multiple Source Number in Call File Asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk, voip, dialplan

i want to make call between 2 people which means i want to call the First person and if he answers it dials the second person's number.
First person has multiple numbers and it should dial each number one by one until one of them answers.

I'm using call file and using 'Channel' for First person(it's expected the it should call the First person at the beginning then call the second person) and it consumes the 'Dial' application for making call with the second person 
call file:

```
Channel:SIP/313
Context:ext-local
Application:Dial
Data:SIP/300
Priority:1
Archive:yes
Account:888000
```

is it possible to make multiple call in 'Channel' then make calls one by one? if so how can i make it happen?

remember, i don't want this feature for destination numbers and i know how to make call with multiple destinations (Data:SIP/300&SIP/400)

thank you in advance, any suggestion would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want via dialplan and use Local type channel. Ringgroups, followme, anything.

For freepbx it will be like  this

```
Channel:Local/313@from-internal/n
Context:ext-local
Application:Dial
Data:SIP/300
Priority:1
Archive:yes
Account:888000
```

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-local-channels/

**PS** I highly not recommend do your own dialling core, there WILL be more issues. Use already known projects like vicidial.org

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correct then do this in `313@ext_local` ...

```
exten => 313,1,dial(SIP/first_extension,15)
; if dial was timed out (15s) or answered and hanguped then next priority will executed
; so next should check ${DIALSTATUS} and only if not answered dial another extension
; for example...
exten => 313,2,execif($["${DIALSTATUS}"="ANSWERED"]?hangup(16):dial(SIP/second_extension,20))
; If first dial was answered the second priority only makes a hangup (sign ?) else (sign :) second extension will be dialed
```